# Nodejs Child and Worker usage for internal application

Tags: multithreading, node.js, cluster-computing, child-process

I am creating a simple server for my internal application with 2cores system 4GB memory. The design is like this:

4 Webservers:Port (WS1:8000 and WS2:3002 and WS3:80 and WS4:110) 
WS1:8000 -> UDP and TCPv4 -> independent multiprocessing
WS2:3002 -> UDP and TCPv4 and TCPv6 -> independent multiprocessing
WS3:80 -> TCPv4 and TCPv6 -> independent multiprocessing
WS4:110 -> POP3 -> independent multiprocessing

I am trying to use cluster for WS1 / WS2 / WS3 / WS4; 
and using child processes further for each protocol to cater to multiple continuous requests each as a process. 
What am I doing wrong here? Any simple way for collaborating this?

Comment: Let me get this, You are trying to use Node.js `cluster` module with four worker processes, right?

Comment: @Салман - Yes, that is the code I am writing - 4 workers. Each of the 4 workers will have specific workers for protocols each. That in turn will have multiple processes (Protocols) for specific connections one a limit for a specific connection is reached or if there is streaming or from a specific ip. Seems like nodejs runs threading internally. Found no documentation on this though. Need this for video/media streaming.